# Mysql Error 1205 Lock wait time exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: php, mysql, locking

What kind of precautions can I take (if I actually can) in my scrip to avoid getting this error.

```
Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait time
out exceeded; try restarting transaction in C:\wamp\www\library\Zend\Db\Statemen
t\Pdo.php on line 234
```

I understand this is a database error, but is there a way how I can check for locked tables before I run my update query ? 
Like check if there the table that I am updating is free, before actually updating it

Thanks guys,
Aman

Comment: locking entire tables doesn't happen too often in innodb. it supports row-level locks and you'd have to check EVERY row that your update might be involved with.

Comment: I actually have a function which updates 1 row at a time using "id" , Is it possible I place something at the beginning of the function that checks for that 1 row to be free ?